# Accessing Column of type "Java Object" in a Birt report with cascaded queries

Tags: birt

I am having some trouble with a Birt report and I don't seem to be able to sort it out. To me it looks as if this might be a Birt limitation, so I'm asking here. If it is, I can stop breaking my head on this:

- I have a Data Set "A" that contains one column called "metadata" of type "Java Object"
- I have a second Data Set "B", which is a sub-query, that binds to the "metadata" column of Data Set "A". B itself again has a colum called "affected" of type "Java Object"
- In my third Data Set "C" I bind to the "affected" column of Data Set "B" and has a column named "family" of type "Java Object"

What I find particularly strange here, is that I can see the value for family being retrieved correctly in the debugger, but if I try to access it, it's always null. If I however set the type of the column to String, I get a non-null value. So is there any reason, why Birt is doing this?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

From past experience, I think the answer is that BIRT can only represent relatively simple datatypes - essentially characters, dates and numbers (it does seem to be able to cope with CLOBs, but then they are essentially long character strings).

Since it is unable to represent object fields, these are presented as NULLs in the report. If you set the datatype of an object field to be string, it will display the binary contents of the object as a string of hexadecimal digits. (At least, this has been my experience when inadvertently returning objects from MySQL queries.)

Comment: It is not quite correct. If I output a "Java Object" field on Level 1 or 2 it is output by calling "toString" on the object and I get a string representation of my object. in Level 3 it's simply null and I don't know why.

Comment: @Chris: As I said, this was from my past experience reporting object types from databases - since you are not reporting from a SQL database, my experience is probably not very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the Java Object is being stored as a blob in your database, then BIRT won't be able to interpret it directly as far as I know.

Are you using an oracle database?  If you were to connect through an alternate client (not your java application), would you be able to query the field and get meaningful data?  (As in, is it serialized data, or stored in a blob format)?

Comment: I am not using a Database at all ... I have created my own DataSource that queries a remote BlazeDS server unsing AMF3. So my reports model consists of a POJO model.